# IE7 and 8 smaller font-size issues with SIFR

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, sifr

my website http://tweetMP.org.au uses SIFR to render the flash font h2 headings.

If you compare the site between Firefox and IE7/8 you'll notice the headings are noticably smaller in IE (7 and 8 only - IE6 looks fine).

Adjusting the font-size on my ie(7 and 8 specific css) does nothing.

Any ideas why this is the case?

-V

Comment: If you disable sIFR, the font size is also smaller?

Comment: Mark, it is not smaller. IE7 and 8 display the same font-size as firefox when I disable siFR

Comment: Okay. In that case, this clearly shouldn't be happening… could you create a test case with just one headline and as little CSS as possible? Will be easier to diagnose.

Comment: Sure, i'll create this for you tonight

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting the font size within the sifr config file, something similar to this: (make note of the font-size element).  This insures that the font size is carried out within the sifr and might help you out. if it doesn't let me know there's one more solution i can think of :)

sIFR.replace({
selector: '.din-20-bold',
src: 'fonts/din.swf',
highsrc: 'fonts/din.swf',
css: {
'.sIFR-root' : { 'text-transform': 'uppercase' , 'color':'#FFFFFF', 'text-align':'right', 'width':'484px', '**font-size':'20px**', 'font-weight':'bold'},
},
wmode: 'transparent',
paddingTop: 0
});

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be from using pixels (px) for the font size. Although ems (em) are the modern way to size fonts, percentages (%) display more consistently across browsers. Try that, and test the sIFR again. For more info, read the articles below, one of which (on A List Apart) quotes:

> A fix to the exaggerated text resizing
>   of IE6 and IE7 is to size the body
>   using a percentage

[CSS Font-Size: em vs. px vs. pt vs. percent](http://www.kyleschaeffer.com/?p=18)

[How to Size Text in CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/)